# $A \cap(A \cup B) = A$ for all sets $A$ and $B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> For all sets $A$ and $B$, $$A \cap(A \cup B) = A.$$

I get that this is true informally, but what would be the notation to formally prove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Frequently, the easiest method for showing some set $X$ and some set $Y$ are equal is this:  first, show that any element $x\in X$ also satisfies $x\in Y$ -- which proves that $X\subseteq Y$.  Then, show that any element $y\in Y$ also satisfies $y\in X$, proving that $Y\subseteq X$.

If $X\subseteq Y$, and $Y\subseteq X$, then necessarily $X=Y$.

So, start off with an element $x$ which is in $A\cap(A\cup B)$, and show that $x\in A$. Then, show that any element $y\in A$ also satisfies $y\in A\cap(A\cup B)$.

It might help you to remember the following two facts:

1. Every element of $A\cap X$ is both an element of $A$ and an element of $X$ -- and so in particular is definitely a member of $A$.
2. If $x\in X$ and $x\in Y$, then $x\in X\cap Y$.

**Edit:** Here's a start.

Suppose that $x\in A\cap (A\cup B)$. Then by definition of the intersection, we must have $x\in A$ and $x\in A\cup B$. In particular, $x\in A$.

Now, see if you can show that any element $x\in A$ must also be in $A\cap(A\cup B)$.

Comment: Is this adequate?

Suppose element x is in A ∩ (A ∪ B).  It follows then that x must be an element in A because A ∪ B intersected by A is just A.  Suppose y is an element in A.  It follows that y is also an element in A ∩ (A ∪ B) because A is = to A ∩ (A ∪ B).

Comment: No, this is not adequate -- you've used the fact that you're trying to prove!

Comment: @user2461994 I updated with a couple more hints.  Try giving it another go.

Comment: Suppose x is in A ∩ (A ∪ B).  x must also be an element in A because any element in A ∪ B must also be present in A.  How is that?

Comment: I have a feeling thats still not right.  I am not sure how to think about this in the right way.

Comment: @user2461994 I updated it with one final hint.  I hope it helps.

Comment: Suppose that x ∈ A. By unifying A and B, x becomes an element of A ∪ B.  When A ∪ B is intersected by A, it still contains x.  So since x ∈ A, x ∈ A ∩ (A ∪ B) is also true.

(Thanks for your patience. How is this?)

Comment: That looks good!

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $A\subseteq X$ then we have $A\cap X=A\ $ (these are actually equivalent). 
Then apply this for $X:=A\cup B$.

Answer (score 0):

$$A\cap(A\cup B)=(A\cap A)\cup(A\cap B)$$ Moving on $A\cup(A\cap B)$

If $A \subseteq B$  then $A \cap B=A$ and this equality happens.